# Inactivate Prints inside function?

Tags: hold, output

If one has a piece of code with some prints, he can inactivate them using inactivate, like

```
Inactivate[Print["test"];,Print]; (*returns nothing*)
```

Hower, I cannot use inactivate to deactivate prints inside a funciton

```
testfunction[a_,b_]:=(
c=a+b;
Print["The result is ", c];
);
Inactivate[testfunction[1,1];,Print]; (*returns "The result is 2"*)
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Maybe a good workaround is to avoid using Print? Why do you use it? To achieve what?

Comment: You are misusing the second argument of Inactivate. If you leave it out the Inactivate works:  `Inactivate[testfunction[1, 1]]`

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I have a very complex function that prints logs on screen of what is does. I do not want to removethe prints from the code, cause sometimes I run it once. But If Ihave to run it 1000 times, the prints are a problem. Now, to fix the issue I would need to rewrite/adjust the original function, I was looking for a cheaper solution

Comment: @DanielHuber I didn-t specify my reasons, but I wanted to disable only the prints, not the whole function. If I remove the second argument, the function will not define c, in this example. That's not what I want. The function should define c, without printing.

Comment: If you absolutely, positively have to use `Print` in this way, and can't accomplish the "logs" via a more sane method, you can enclose execution(s) with something like `Block[{Print}, Print[___] = Nothing[];
 ...Your stuff here...]`

Comment: @ciao thanks for suggestion. Any example of a "more sane method"? Interested to learn alternatives

Comment: @GiorgioBusoni - many ways, have a look at `Reap` and `Sow`, or the intrinsic `Message` capabilities. Personally, I'd use the latter: you can turn messages on/off at a fine-grained level using `On` and `Off` or `Quiet`.